# What is a .mozilla folder doing in ~/?

Tags: centos

On one of my servers a .mozilla folder was created while adding a user. I found it in one other user folder, but not the initial user that I created.

Where did it come from?

Im using CentOS 5.x.

**Edit:** This is what "locate mozilla" turns up:

```
/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/mozilla.pp
/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/previous/modules/mozilla.pp
/etc/skel/.mozilla
/etc/skel/.mozilla/extensions
/etc/skel/.mozilla/plugins
/home/refwcx/.mozilla
/home/refwcx/.mozilla/extensions
/home/refwcx/.mozilla/plugins
/usr/lib64/mozilla
/usr/lib64/mozilla/extensions
/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins
/usr/lib64/xulrunner-1.9/mozilla-xremote-client
/usr/lib64/xulrunner-1.9/run-mozilla.sh
/usr/share/mozilla
/usr/share/doc/selinux-policy-2.4.6/html/apps_mozilla.html
/usr/share/mime/application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/x-mozilla-bookmarks.xml
/usr/share/mozilla/extensions
/usr/share/selinux/targeted/mozilla.pp
```

A yum package "xulrunner" was installed. Anyone know what this is? Did someone install this, or did it come with an update, or is it a dependency of some package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps someone installed firefox or a derivative on the server and it created default settings in `/etc/skel`?

Comment: Turns out it game from system-config-date. xulrunner is a dependency.

Answer (score 3):

It comes from... Firefox. My first guest is your server run at runlevel 5 (GUI) and user remote desktop to surf the web.

---

> A yum package "xulrunner" was installed. Anyone know what this is? Did
>   someone install this, or did it come with an update, or is it a
>   dependency of some package?

[xulrunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xulrunner) provides the XUL runtime environment for Gecko apps (Firefox, Thunderbird, ...). It is installed when you install a Gecko app, no need to worry.